# nginx set URL rewrite rules

Tags: nginx

Prior to now, I had my api be in root, for exmple: `https://api.example.com`

Because I use CI, I need every path to be rewritten to index, like so:

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args
}
```

Now, I moved to versioning the api, so each version is in a subdirectory, for example: `https://api.example.com/0.0.1/`

How can I change my rule to fit the new pattern? (if folder then something, use that folder's index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you would like a general solution, in which case you could offload the rewrite to a named location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^(/\d\.\d\.\d)(/.*)$  $1/index.php?q=$2&$args last;
    rewrite ^                     /index.php?q=$uri&$args last;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.